# What control do I need to show video from a webcam?

Tags: c#, wpf, webcam, motion-detection, aforge

I want to integrate a webcam and I am using Aforge.NET framework. What control do I need to show the webcam video. My simple program will get the webcam, put it in the combo box and when i click 'ok', I can see that the camera is running but I don't see the video. C#/WPF

`

```
<Window x:Class="MyWebCam.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="425">
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="videoPlayer" Margin="15"></Image>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="cbxDevices" MinWidth="150" Margin="15" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="left" SelectionChanged="cbxDevices_SelectionChanged" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnOk" Content="OK" MinWidth="100" Margin="15" Click="btnOk_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using AForge;
using AForge.Imaging;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.VFW;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Controls;
using System.Drawing;
using AForge.Vision.Motion;
using AForge.Vision;

namespace MyWebCam
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //opened video source
        private VideoCaptureDevice videoSource = null;

        //motion detector
        MotionDetector detector = new MotionDetector(
            new TwoFramesDifferenceDetector(),
            new MotionAreaHighlighting());

        FilterInfoCollection videoDevices;
        private bool deviceExist = false;
        private string device;

        //video device
        public string VideoDevice
        {
            get { return device; }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getCamList();
        }

        private void getCamList()
        {
            try
            {
                videoDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
                cbxDevices.Items.Clear();
                if (videoDevices.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException();
                }
                deviceExist = true;
                foreach (FilterInfo device in videoDevices)
                {
                    cbxDevices.Items.Add(device.Name);
                }
                cbxDevices.SelectedIndex = 0; //make first cam default
            }
            catch (ApplicationException)
            {
                deviceExist = false;
                cbxDevices.Items.Add("No webcams on your system");
            }
        }

        private void cbxDevices_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            device = videoDevices[cbxDevices.SelectedIndex].MonikerString;
            if (cbxDevices.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                videoSource = new VideoCaptureDevice(videoDevices[cbxDevices.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
                videoSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);

            }
        }
        private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            // get new frame
            Bitmap video = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame;
            // process the frame
            videoPlayer.Source = video;   //this is where i'm having the problem

        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            videoSource.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing built into WPF for this. But I can recommend Jeremiah Morrill's WPF MediaKit, which you can find at http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/

The `VideoCaptureElement` in that toolkit can render video from any capture source (which would include any web cam) into WPF.

Answer (score 1):

We are using VLC Dot NET Control. This is working like a charm, also with Webcam: http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/